# Visualisation of the memory layout of C structs

Tags: c, parsing, struct, visualization, declaration

I'm currently working on a C project that interfaces heavily with other assembly code. We're having self-made visualizations of control blocks and structs that we're using and I'm locking for a process on how to automate this process.

Since we have a C struct equivalency for every assembly control block and we're programming for a pretty rare architecture, the easiest way would probably to visualize the C structs.

I'm more or less looking for a way to automatically obtain graphs like the "TCP pseudo-header for checksum computation (IPv6)" from the TCP wiki page:

[TCP pseudo-header for checksum computation (IPv6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y0FV.png)

Sadly, I haven't found any open-source tools that are able to generate such visualizations from C header files. Is there a way to generate such images or html representations without manually writing them?

EDIT: Thanks to Alexey Frunze for the idea, with the utility pahole it's possible to extract the real memory layout of all used structs from the DWARF sections of an object file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways to do it is to compile your C code with those structs and extract the structure information from the debugging info of the object/executable file. Otherwise you're looking into finding/making structure parsers or hacking clang.

**UPD**: Never tried it, but there's [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/), which might be useful.

Comment: Extracting the struct layout out of generated debug info is an interesting idea, especially because you should be able to get the layout information of bitfields as well. Still I'm surprised that this requirement seems so rare that no public tools are availible.

Comment: @FrederikHartmann The problem is that you need a nearly complete compiler front-end in order to parse the code and then there is/was quite a bit of variation between compiler-specific features, meaning you'd still need to pre-process the source code somehow (i.e. remove unsupported pragmas and other non-standard things, gcc attributes, etc). So, there's almost always going to be some limitation, unless you write code per the language standard. On top of that you have various compiler-specific command-line options affecting alignment. So, it's hard to make one good and universal tool.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The only failsave way to get this would probably to have it generated by the compiler. Clang has something in regard to C++ objects. Maybe I might be able to get this running. http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/12/17/dumping-a-c-objects-memory-layout-with-clang

Answer (score 0):

The layout of some C aggregate (`struct`, `union`, array) is *implementation* specific because of [data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) constraints (required by your particular [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)).

You might use the debugger (e.g. `ptype` command of `gdb`). Notice that `ddd` has a graphical display.

If you have *many* structures, you could consider customizing your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/). You'll develop your particular MELT extension to show the layout. It could take weeks (because you'll need to understand some of the GCC internals).

Comment: Sure, but if we avoid bitfields (that are a giant mess for a save layout) you could generate a layout for a given struct, either by specifying the alignment or by #pragma pack

Comment: But that layout remains implementation specific.

Comment: I don't think that the layout is implementation specific, if we're able to guaranty that no padding is taking place since the order of elements in a struct is not implementation specific, only the padding.

Comment: An x86-64 Linux system has a different layout than an ARMv7 Android one (in particular, because `sizeof(long)` is probably different)

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a C toolbox that can, among other things, diagram C types of any complexity. It imports and comprehends Dwarf information in code compiled with "-g", and and can dump out whatever you want in "dot" format (which can be displayed via any number of tools.)

(It's also a programming language that uses this Dwarf comprehension ability to access library/program internals directly, with zero glue-code or linking necessary, at runtime.)

See: https://github.com/jasonnyberg/j2/wiki/Diagramming-C-types-using-j2

The j2 system can read and comprehend Dwarf information; As a debugging feature, it can also dump items you select in the form of the "dot" language, which allows the type information hierarchy to be displayed in graphical form. The "stack" function, which displays items on the interpreter's top layer of stack, also dumps these items out to /tmp/VMRES_STACK.dot.

To diagram an item, all that's needed is to reference it by name (if it's not already on the stack), and then invoke the stack function with, "stack!" (which references the function "stack" by name, and then evaluates it via the "!" operator.)

Once you have the interpreter running (see link above for the interpreter itself and an actual example run which dumps a graph of a structure), you just need to A) "import" the library:

```
j2> loadlib([test/build/libtestlib.so]) @testlib
```

then B) reference your imported structure (adding it to the interpreter's stack):

```
j2> testlib.teststruct
```

and finally, C) display the stack (textually, and as a side effect, generating the file /tmp/VMRES_STACK.dot):

```
j2> stack!
```

The graph contained within /tmp/VMRES_STACK.dot can be displayed via any of a number of graphviz/dot viewers, such as xdot:

```
bash> xdot /tmp/VMRES_STACK.dot
```

[xdot /tmp/VMRES_STACK.dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGeIH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a struct layout visualizer and happy to share my findings: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RamonViladomat.StructLayout2022 - Seems to work well. Understands structs, unions, cache line size...